# A faster way to read lines in text files quickly

Tags: vb.net, text, task-parallel-library, streamreader

My application is looking at huge text files (upwards to half a million lines) from a proxy server log. The problem is that a normal StreamRead iteration of the logs can take an excessive amount of time to process, so I'm looking for something faster.

On the form, the user picks the file they need to parse and enters up to three site filters to check for. The application then opens the file and begins to parse the date stamp and website URL from each line in the file. The average speed is about ***two lines per second***, so for a file with 200,000 lines in it, this process will take about 28 hours to process a file.

I've been reading on the [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, and I'm thinking this would probably be the route to take, but Microsoft doesn't give a very good example, so how can I can accomplish it?

Comment: How about trying [IO.File.ReadAllText("File location")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx)?

Comment: Are you saying that the StreamReader is only reading 2 lines per second?  That seems awfully slow to me.  How long is each line?

Comment: Could you show us the important parts of your code?

Comment: It takes .5 seconds to read a line and parse the date stamp and website URL? You don't need Tasks. You need to change your algorithm.

Comment: Any method that causes all lines to be read is a mistake waiting to happen, unless you know that the file will be small.  As mentioned earlier, two lines per second seems slow.

Comment: Your problem is that you randomly assume that the StreamReader is the problem. You probably don't have evidence for that. Find out what the *real* problem is.

Comment: I've build a similar tool with great success by using Reactive Extensions. The form stays responsive, allowing resizing and graceful closing while the file is being processed and showing up progressively in the UI. I basically set up Rx to observe the lines of the file as they are coming in, and set up how I want to process them. You can configure how the process is parallelized by assigning a scheduler for the reading of the file, and another for the processing. If you are interested, I can get you the code as a sample.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could use **File.ReadLines()** when reading large files.
According to MSDN :

> The **ReadLines** and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, **ReadLines** can be more efficient.

For more detail, see [MSDN File.ReadLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of guessing about why it is slow, is it reading the file, processing the lines, etc. start by measuring how long it takes to read the file line-by-line.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim stpw As New Stopwatch
    Dim path As String = "path to your file here"
    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(path)
    Dim linect As Integer = 0
    stpw.Restart()

    Do While Not sr.EndOfStream
        Dim s As String = sr.ReadLine
        linect += 1
    Loop
    stpw.Stop()
    sr.Close()
    Debug.WriteLine(stpw.Elapsed.ToString)
    Debug.WriteLine(linect)
End Sub
```

I ran this against a test file I have that is 20MB.  It is close to 3,000,000 lines long(the lines are very short).  It took about .3 of a second to run.

After you run this you will know whether the problem is the read or the processing, or both.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, dbasnett... the results were:
00:00:00.6991336
172900

Believe it or not, I found the problem. I had the textbox inside a GroupBox and was using the GroupBox.Text property to update statistics back to the user, using GroupBox.Refresh() to update the line x of y and matches found, etc. so the user had some idea of what was being found.

By leaving that information out and putting in a progress bar, the speed of the scans went up exponentially. Using 3 filters, I was able to parse 172900 lines in a matter of 3:19 minutes:

```
Scan complete!
Process complete!
Scanned 172900 lines out of 172900 lines.
Percentage (icc): 0.0052% (900 matches)
Percentage (facebook): 0.0057% (988 matches)
Percentage (illinois): 0.0005% (95 matches)
Total Matches: 1983
Elapsed Time: 00:03:19.1088851
```